# Storing login detail for SSH/telnet connections in Windows Terminal

Tags: authentication, ssh, ssh-keys, windows-terminal

Is there a way to store the passwords for SSH connections in the new Windows Terminal?

As much as I love the new Windows Terminal and all the fancy features that it offers, not being able to store the login details for my SSH or Telnet connections is kind of a deal-breaker for me.

I roughly have 200 devices that I connect to over SSH or Telnet, and some of them I access multiple times in a day so, having the ability to store the login details securely is crucial.

I have also tried setting up the SSH keys for authentication but, it becomes overwhelming very quickly as there are always new devices getting added. Sometimes, the device on the other end is not capable of storing SSH keys.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Agree with Martin - There are probably some suggestions we can make to help (especially Martin, who is an SSH expert), but many of us won't contribute to an off-topic question.  I monitor the "windows-terminal" tag both here and on Super User, and I know Martin does the same for at least the "ssh" tag, so we'll see it there when you re-post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, saving your passwords is very unsafe and Windows Terminal isn't supposed to / doesn't do that.

You should consider managing SSH keys directly, it might be a bit harder to use / manage but is safer and stays bad people away.

However you can automatize the way you register new SSH keys using a shell script .